# Set up properly Foundation 6 with Angular 2 and then use the modal of foundation in component

Tags: jquery, angular, typescript, zurb-foundation, zurb-foundation-6

I am using foundation 6 css and angular 4 but its not working properly. I cant use the javascript of foundation especially the modal of foundation. And all directions on the web are directed to boostrap and angular. Hopefully the foundation and angular community can help.

The question is how can I set up foundation 6 css and scss and angualar 2 framework properly and then use the modal window from foundation 6 thank you.

Answer (score 0):

To get the javascript working, you need to initialize the javascript using jQuery within your app.component.ts - i do it in the ngOnInit function - like this

```
ngOnInit() {
   $(document).foundation()
}
```

That way, all javascript will become initialized within your app - assuming you've setup your project correctly (i.e. added javascript files to .angular-cli.json - scripts array)

You probably need to decide whether you want to use css or scss with your project setup, as choosing one will simplify the process quite a bit.

If you have general issues of how to setup the project and import the styles, comment my post and i will update my answer with what you need to know.

Kind regards Chris

Comment: sorry for the late response I had paused on the project just got back to it, when I added the `$(document).foundation()` to the ngOnInit in the app.component.ts it didnt work but when I added it to the individual component with the modal in the html it worked. Is there a way or something I am doing wrong in order to make it more global rather than declaring it in every component I have. Thank you

Comment: Are you using any server side rendering with your project?

Comment: Also, when you say it does not work, does nothing happen?, or do you get an error? In case of an error, what error did you get when trying to initialise the modal?